# Extend header to full width on Wordpress.com theme with custom CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I'm looking to extend the header image to be full width on a client's blog which is hosted on Wordpress.com, but it doesn't seem like the theme supports it natively. Something seems to be cropping the image automatically.

Is there any way this can be done using CSS?

http://ryanmangansitblog.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apologies - the section with the clouds underneath the nav, currently set to 'welcometomyblog3.png'.

Comment: `#hero .hero-content p {
max-width: 770px;
}` remove this from your `style.css` and it will be full width.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for your help Azrael!

Comment: I've put it as an awnser below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is caused because of the `<p>` element located in `#hero .hero-content` which has a `max-width` variable set in `style.css`, if you remove this rule `#hero .hero-content p { max-width: 770px; }` your problem should be solved, and the image should be shown full width.